# How can I move the legend plotting a Weibull distribution (wblr object in WeibullR package) so that I can see all the chart?

Tags: r, plot, legend, weibull

I'm trying to plot a Weibull distribution by using the package WeibullR, but the legend box takes half of the space of the plotted chart. I'd like to move the legend box outside of the chart. I've noticed that the text moved (there is more space between two horizontal lines in the legend and the margins are bigger) when I zoomed in or changed the window size.
I've tried manipulating the options of the wblr object, notably legend.text.size and legend.position, but I can't find anything satisfying.

Plus, the problem occurs whether or not there is a fit.

Here is the code of an example :
t = c(10000, 10000, 20000, 20000, 30000, 30000, 30000, 30000,
40000, 50000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 70000, 70000, 70000,
80000, 80000, 80000, 80000, 90000, 90000, 100000)
w<-wblr(t)
plot.wblr(w)

Here are the images I get :
[In the Plot corner of R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW5a1.png)
and
[Once I zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR3ZU.png)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I do not have the package installed, but could you add options that specify that the data is logged, e.g. `plot.wblr(w, log="x,y")` or `plot.wblr(w, canvas="lognormal")` ? Check the plot options and see if that helps. Generally speaking, this seems to be a base plot, so always dependent on the size of the output device. Finding appropriate dimensions may also help.

Comment: I've tried plot.wblr(w, log="x,y")  (the warning message was: "In plot.wblr(w, log = "xy") :
  log option is to be depreciated in favor of canvas") and plot.wblr(w, canvas="lognormal") gave me a similar plot, the graduations on the y axis were simply slightly different, but the scale was the same as before. You see, the wblr object has already its own canvas and scale implemented.
I don't really see how this was supposed to move the legend box though. 
What in the plot do you recommend I change when you say 'finding appropriate dimensions ' ?